# Get Signal from tap on UIButton in Reactive Cocoa 4

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

How can I create a `Signal` from a tap on a `UIButton`?

[So far I tried to use *target/action*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204542/create-cocoaaction-for-uibutton-to-read-from-uitextfields-and-start-new-game), but have come to think that there might be an easier way.

In an [article of Colin Eberhardt,](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/04/28/reactive-cocoa-3-continued.html) it is stated that `Signals` are appropriate for UI actions. But when I tried to make my around with *target/action*, I needed to create a `CocoaAction` was ultimately initialised with a `SignalProducer`.

What I want is some `Signal` that emits its `next` events with every user tap. I then want to transform this Signal to read from `UITextFields` and carry on those values to use them in my application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using convenience functions from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/NachoSoto/25b0003c1b15d7d11a8d) by @NachoSoto, I was able to achieve this quite simply with `signalForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)` :

```
self.startButton
      .signalForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
      .map { _ in (self.name1TextField.text!, self.name2TextField.text!)}
      .observe { event in
          if let names = event.value {
              print("received names \(names)")
          }
       }
```

Comment: Looks good! You probably want to use `observeNext` though, since you're only interested in values (not completion, disposal, etc).

Answer (score 4):

```
 self.startButton
     .rac_signalForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
     .subscribeNext { event in
         if let names = event.value {
            print("received names \(names)")
         }
     }
```